# Display table content using querystring

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio

I have one page in asp, contain three table ( Pending order, confirmed order and rejected order). This three table under one header. When user click on pending order word on header, page will display only pending table. This three information in on code page using asp. How can get this function work using the query string?

Detail:
As refer image below, current state all the information in one page,

[image]

The request is when user click on the pending order, it only display the pending table, also apply to confirm and rejected.

Each table using grid view function and i want to use the query string. If I use to create separate page for this,it will involve to many definition.

Update the code:

The code for the every table i use grid view in the aspx file.

```
<div class="col-md-12 account-title">
                    Your Pending Orders Confirmation
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 table-responsive">
                    <asp:GridView ID="grdvwPendingOrder" ShowFooter="false" AutoGenerateColumns="False" runat="server" CssClass="table table-bordered text-center" 
                        OnRowCommand="grdvwPendingOrder_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="grdvwPendingOrder_RowDataBound" EmptyDataRowStyle-ForeColor="Red" 
                        EmptyDataRowStyle-BackColor="White" EmptyDataText="No Records Found">
                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="table-title text-center" />
                        <RowStyle CssClass="account-content text-center" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                <HeaderTemplate>Order No.</HeaderTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblOrderNo" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id") %>' />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                <HeaderTemplate>Date</HeaderTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "OrderDate", "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>' />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                <HeaderTemplate>Placed By</HeaderTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblPlacedby" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CustomerName") %>' />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                <HeaderTemplate>Status</HeaderTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "OrderStatus") %>' />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                <HeaderTemplate>Actions</HeaderTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnReview" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-success" Text="Review" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id") %>' CommandName="Review" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                </div>
                <!-- Pagination -->
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 padLROff">
                    <ucPageControl:PageControl ID="PendingOrderPageControl" Title="" runat="server" Visible="false" />
                </div>
```

Code for pending order.

The confirmed and rejected in the same file. 
Now I want to build a header for this type as table above. As mention, if i separate the type to different aspx file, it will involve to many definition.

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: Why do you want to use the query string?Write a jQuery or javascript function to hide all the other tables except for the one that the user clicked on

Comment: hi rene, i update my post.